# Reading numbers from text and outputting average

Tags: c++, file, loops, if-statement, while-loop

So I am working to read text from a file (line by line) and output the `ID`, average of 4 grades following the `ID`, and the letter grade. So the letter grade for any average grade of 50 or above is `S`, anything below 50 is a `U`, and 2 excused classes results in the letter grade `I`. (No S or U if more than or equal to 2 excused).

So lets say file has the numbers:

```
42 50 51 57 52
48 90 -1 60 -1
40 46 -1 59 45
47 50 -1 49 50
```

The output should look something like this:

```
ID=42 Avg=52.5 Grade=S
ID=48 Excused=2 Grade=I
ID=40 Avg=50.0 Grade=S
ID=47 Avg=49.7 Grade=U
```

Number of Grades of Type

```
S    U    I
2    1    1
```

[This is the output I am receiving from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sZom.jpg)

It is reading all the numbers, but i need it to read the first number as `ID` and following 4 numbers as grade.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in;
    ofstream results;
    string filename;
    char grade;
    int S = 0, U = 0, I = 0, i = 0, ID, excused = 0, avg;
    double allscores = 0;

    cout << "Enter the name of the file that has the scores of students: " << endl;
    cin >> filename;

    cout << "Enter the number of scores for each student: " << endl;
    cin >> ID;

    in.open(filename);
    results.open("results.txt");

    if (in)
    {
        while (in >> ID)
        {
            int first = 0

            for (i = 0; i<=4; i++)
            {
                if (first == -1)
                    excused++;
                else
                    allscores += first;
            }
            if (first > 4)
            {
                avg = allscores / (4 - excused);

                if (avg >= 50.0)
                {
                    grade = 'S';
                    S++;
                    cout << "ID=" << ID << " Avg=" << avg << " Grade =" << grade << endl;

                }
                else
                {
                    grade = 'U';
                    U++;
                    cout << "ID=" << ID << " Avg=" << avg << " Grade =" << grade << endl;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                grade = 'I';
                I++;
                cout << "ID=" << ID << " Excused=" << excused << " Grade =" << grade << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Couldn't open file\n";
    }

    cout << "Number of Grades of Type" << endl;
    cout << "S   " << "U   " << "I" << endl;
    cout << S << "   " << U << "   " << I << endl;

    in.close();
    results.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are just reading ID not the rest of the numbers

Comment: What can I do to fix that? I'm pretty new to this whole file thing... should i add another else statement?

Comment: What does excused mean?

Comment: what does first do? how actually you are calculating average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `int first=0` is not being assigned any value other than 0 in your code so the statement `if(first>4)` will always be false and result the output your are getting.

You can do something like this:

```
    while (in >> ID)//this is supposed to get the ID of each student, in order for that to happen you need to read all the 4 scores inside this loop before coming here and reading the next ID,otherwise everything will read as an ID
    {
       int first = 0
       excused=0;//you need to reset excused on every iteration
       allscores=0;//you need to reset allscore on every iteration
       for (i = 0; i<4; i++)
       {//here you need to get all the 4 scores
           in>>first;//get each score in first
           if (first == -1)
             excused++;
           else
             allscores += first;
       }

       if(excused<2)//instead of if(first>4)
            ...//do your calculation for average score
       else
            ...//set the grade to 'I'...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in;
    ofstream results;
    string filename;
    char grade;
    int S = 0, U = 0, I = 0, i = 0, ID, excused = 0, avg;
    double allscores = 0;

    cout << "Enter the name of the file that has the scores of students: " << endl;
    cin >> filename;

    cout << "Enter the number of scores for each student: " << endl;
    cin >> ID;

    in.open(filename);
    results.open("results.txt");

    if (in)
    {
        while (in >> ID)
        {
            int first = 0;
            excused = 0;
            allscores = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                in >> first;
                if (first == -1)
                    excused++;
                else
                    allscores += first;
            }

            if (excused < 2)
            {
                avg = allscores / (4 - excused);

                if (avg >= 50.0)
                {
                    grade = 'S';
                    S++;
                    results << "ID=" << ID << " Avg=" << avg << " Grade =" << grade << endl;

                }
                else
                {
                    grade = 'U';
                    U++;
                    results << "ID=" << ID << " Avg=" << avg << " Grade =" << grade << endl;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                grade = 'I';
                I++;
                results << "ID=" << ID << " Excused=" << excused << " Grade =" << grade << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Couldn't open file\n";
    }

    results << "Number of Grades of Type" << endl;
    results << "S   " << "U   " << "I" << endl;
    results << S << "   " << U << "   " << I << endl;

    in.close();
    results.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

After the code I have it output to a file named "results". 
Thanks for the help. I guess my while loop was the biggest mistake.
 
Especially not adding in the `in >> first` portion.